# Is there a good way using ANTLR4 to check for specific tokens without parsing?

Tags: java, token, antlr4

I have an ANTLR4 grammar that contains tokens for "filenames" and "URLs" but the language also includes strings and string expressions (which might turn out to be filenames or URLs).  Is there a good way to call just the tokenizer on some string in my interpreter and see if the string is a filename or URL according to my token rules?  I just want to special case those cases where the script I am interpreting has created one of those things on the fly, so I can treat such strings specially.

```
lexer  // this I already have (or something like this)
FileName: ([A-Za-z]':')?('\\'?[-_.A-Za-z0-9]+)+ ;
URL: ([A-Za-z]+':')?'/'?('/'?[-_.A-Za-z0-9]+)+ ;

Intepreter.java

public boolean isFileName(String string) {
   return antlr.lexer.token(string).type == FileName;  // this is the magic I want
}

Script  // this is what I am looking to understand
  # you get cat pictures, I get paid...
  url = 'https://trojan-server.com/hidden-bitcoin-miner';
  fn = 'c:' + programdirectory() + 'show-cat-pictures.exe';
  download(url, fn);
  exec(fn);
```

Comment: Yes, you can call the lexer nextToken() method in a loop to extract what you want. The lexer works independently from the parser. I do this all the time to extract comments, which are tokens that have a non-default channel.

Comment: @kaby76 I suggest you make an Answer of your Comment. And maybe add an example.

Comment: I would use a regular expression instead of generating a full parser + lexer for such a simple task.

Comment: I already have the full parser and lexer, but since the language is dynamic, users may generate certain tokens at runtime.  I already handle the case where they generate full "sentences" (things that are parseable) by recursively calling the parser in the middle of the walk of the parse tree, but that doesn't easily handle this case.

Comment: Moreover, I don't want the possibility of there being two regular expressions describing the same thing lest they differ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand the question, you would like your interpreter actions which receives strings which are constructed at runtime, to be able to take advantage of your lexer to determine if those strings are URL or file references.

Something like this:

```
doDownloadAction(source: string, dest: string) {
  if (isFilename(source)) {
```

One answer would be to just fire up a new lexer fed by your string, the same way you do when you start a parse, but with no parser ... Something like this (in Typescript, sorry it's what I use for ANTLR):

```
import {LMLexer} from "./LMLexer";
import {CharStreams} from "antlr4ts";

function isFilename(txt: string) {
  const stringLexer = new LMLexer(CharStreams.fromString(txt));
  return stringLexer.nextToken().type == LMLexer.FileName;
}

for ( const str of [ "C:\\Users\\Tony\\file.txt", "http://stackoverflow.com" ]) {
  console.log(str, isFilename(str) ? "is" : "is not", "a filename");
}
```

Comment: I came back to edit this after I actually ran the code, and actually the first comment by @kayby76 also suggests this approach, feel kind of silly. Oh well, maybe someone will post a Java answer, since I think most people use Java.

Comment: I marked it as an answer, because it close enough.  I don't write a lot of JS, but it's close enough to Java to transcribe without too much difficulty.  I would have marked @kayby76's comment as the answer, if they had made it an answer